# What's is Super retina display?

Tags: ios, app-store, ios11, retina-display

According to apple

https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/

**"All new iOS apps and updates for iPhone, including universal apps, must support the Super Retina display of iPhone X."**

My question is

1. How do i make my current app Super retina display enable ?
2. If i don't update my current app to norms of super retina display my app will be removed from store ?

https://www.pocket-lint.com/apps/news/apple/144411-all-future-ios-apps-must-support-iphone-x-s-super-retina-display

**"Any apps that don't support the new criteria will be removed from the App Store"**

Comment: If you scrolled just a little bit further on the developer page you linked, you would have found this link : https://developer.apple.com/ios/update-apps-for-iphone-x/ . Just make sure your app looks good on iPhone X.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to update you app on App Store and give support of Super retina display (iPhone X) for UI and security purpose.

From the Apple officials, they said that starting July 2018, All apps submitted to App store must be build with iOS 11 SDK and must provide support for super retina display.

If you don't update your existing app on App Store then apple will remove it from App Store.

Comment: Can you provide a link confirming this?